# Azure App Service Premium - Securing internal services

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

We are currently running a virtual network with a web cluster (2 servers) hosting our front end .NET web application and a service cluster (2 servers) hosting our internal .NET WCF service which then connects to the database.

So at the moment we have one external IP which points to www.ourwebsite.com which is load balanced over our web cluster. We then have an internal load balancer on an internal IP which points to wcf.outwebsite.local using an internal DNS server so all the traffic to the back end remains in our private virtual network.

We are looking to deploy this onto azure app service premium in an internal network. We would use 2 app pools, 1 for the front end application and one for the backend WCF service so they can scale independently of each other what I cant work out is how we can set internal URL's or IP addresses for the back end WCF service and ensure that they cant be accessed by the outside world.

Does any one know if this is possible in azure app service so we can secure internal services as I cant find anything in there documentation about it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to Azure App Service Environment.

You can control inbound requests via **Network Security Gateways**. See this article:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic/